# writeToFile is writing to file twice

Tags: java, hashmap, printwriter, bufferedwriter, writetofile

I have tried `out.append(s);` However my problems grow out of control. Anyone else see anything my eyes are missing?

```
public void writeToFile()
{
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("course.txt", true)));

        for (String courseName:courseData.keySet())
        {
            Course course = courseData.get(courseName);
            if (!course.isEmpty())
            {
                ArrayList<String> students = course.getStudentList();
                for (String s : students)
                {                        
                    out.println(courseName + "<<<<" + s);                                             
                }
            }
            else
            {
                out.println(courseName + "<<<<");

            }



        }
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(CourseApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

My text file should look like this after I make an entry.

[image]

However this is the result I actually get.

[image]

Comment: `new FileWriter("course.txt", true)` is setting up the `FileWriter` for "append" mode, is this really what you want?

Comment: Can I vote you up Mad! Your the best! Someone was helping me in person and they added that in there.

Comment: Why are you iterating courseData.keySet() and then get the course object? Try "for (Course course: courseData)"

Comment: [Here's the JavaDocs for `FileWriter(String, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.lang.String-boolean-) - feel fee to self answer you question, it might help someone else ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
//use pw.flush() at the end to avoid multiple copies



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;

public class MergeFiles {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException 
    {

        File dir=new File("E:\\videos\\assignments\\fileWork");
        
        File file = new File("E:\\videos\\assignments\\fileWork\\MergeAllAssignments.txt");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(file);
        
        String[] fileNames=dir.list();
        
        for(String files:fileNames) 
        {
            System.out.println("Reading file "+files);
            File f=new File(dir,files);//instance of file to read
            
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));//f>>filereader>>bufferedReader
            
            String line=br.readLine();//reading line by line
            
            while(line!=null) 
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                pw.println(line);
                line=br.readLine();
            }
            
            pw.println("\r\n\n\r\n next days assignment>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
            //to write everything in pw object to destinatio
            
        }
        pw.flush();
    
        pw.close();
        
        System.out.println("Copying completed");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).